# Something keeps changing Firefox home page

Tags: firefox

We just installed the Ubuntu game pack and no matter how many times we change the preferences, the home page is set to ualinux.com.  We even disabled the ualinux.com add-on, but it keeps coming back.

Anyone know how to get rid of it?

Comment: Are you saving thee changes when you try to edit your homepage? If not, try clicking `Save Changes` or something similar.

Comment: How?  I don't see anything that let's me save changes.

Comment: Go to `Help` -> `Restart with Addons disabled` and check if the issue remains.

Comment: Yes, it still remains.  I have wiped the distribution so it doesn't matter any more.